# How to get form data through the Bootstrap forms and convert it into JSON

Tags: jquery, json, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Following is my HTML5 code with bootstrap:

```
<section id="login" class="main-box container-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <form id="login-form" method="post" action="login.php" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset col-sm-5 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login-email">Email-ID</label>
      <input type="email" required class="form-control" id="login-email" placeholder="Enter Email-ID Here">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login-pass">Password</label>
      <input type="password" required class="form-control" id="login-pass" placeholder="Enter Password Here">
      <div class="pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgotPass">
          Forgot Pass?
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
    </label>
    </div>
    <div id="login-response" class="text-danger">
      Enter Credentials To Login!
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block login-me">Login Me</button>
    <article id="login-toggle">
      New User? Click Here To Register!
    </article>
    </form>
</section>
```

This is my jQuery code that I am using to retrieve the form data to store in JSON and make a submit.

```
var data = $('#login-form')[0];
console.log(data);
$('#login-form').submit();
```

However the output of the code which comes is this:

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" action="login.php" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset col-sm-5 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login-email">Email-ID</label>
      <input type="email" required="" class="form-control" id="login-email" placeholder="Enter Email-ID Here">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login-pass">Password</label>
      <input type="password" required="" class="form-control" id="login-pass" placeholder="Enter Password Here">
      <div class="pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgotPass">
          Forgot Pass?
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
    </label>
    </div>
    <div id="login-response" class="text-danger" style="display: none;">
      Enter Credentials To Login!
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block login-me">Login Me</button>
    <article id="login-toggle">
      New User? Click Here To Register!
    </article>
    </form>
```

It's giving the whole code as the output and not the values that are present also the form is not being submit.

Comment: `$('#login-form')[0]` returns the matched DOM node. To get the "form data" you have to use [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: I have used that it returns an empty array. You can try

Comment: Because none of your input elements has a `name`

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions: [ I added textarea to form  check below js files]

## 1 Don't use names and create straight json from html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
function validateForm() { //custom function to validarte a form
  var isValid = true;
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' )
      isValid = false;
  });
  return isValid;
}

var jsoninput = $('#json');
var submit = $('button[type="submit"]');
var form = $('form');
var users = [];
var user = {};
submit.click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(validateForm()) {
    $('input').each(function(e) {
      var type = $(this).attr('type');
      var value = $(this).val();
      user[type] = value; 
    })
    users.push(user);
    console.log(users);
    users = JSON.stringify(users);
    jsoninput.html(users);
    // form.submit(); uncomment this if u like to submit the form
  } else  {
    alert('form is invalid fill some fields');
  }
});
});
</script>
```

## 2 Use names and serialize and change to json:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
//this solutions uses name attribute and serialization to create and json object
var json = $('#json');
var form = $('form');
var group = $('.form-group input'); // specify which group u d like to serialize;
var submit = $('button[type="submit"]');
form.submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // prevebt form submition if u done ur work remove this line;
  var user = group.serializeArray();
  var loginFormObject = {};
  for (var i = user.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var name = user[i].name;
    var value = user[i].value;
    loginFormObject[name] = value;
  }
  loginFormObject = JSON.stringify(loginFormObject);
  console.log(loginFormObject);
  json.text(loginFormObject);
});
});
</script>
```

## 3 HTML FORM:

```
<section id="login" class="main-box container-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<form id="login-form" method="post" action="login.php" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset col-sm-5 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
  <textarea style="width:100%;height: 200px;" id="json" type="" name="json-to-database"></textarea>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="login-email">Email-ID</label>
    <input type="email" required class="form-control" id="login-email" placeholder="Enter Email-ID Here" name="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="login-pass">Password</label>
    <input type="password" required class="form-control" id="login-pass" placeholder="Enter Password Here" name="password">
    <div class="pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgotPass">
      Forgot Pass?
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="login-response" class="text-danger">
    Enter Credentials To Login!
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block login-me">Login Me</button>
  <article id="login-toggle">
    New User? Click Here To Register!
  </article>
</form>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `name` attribute in every `<input>` element.

The name attribute defines the name of the form control and is submitted along with the form control's value when the form is submitted. It is the name part of the name/value pair associated with an element for the purposes of form submission.